# Conflict using Magnific Popup with 'autoScrolling: false,' option from fullPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, magnific-popup, fullpage.js

Opening and then closing a popup using Magnific Popup on a fullPage.js site seems to stop the autoScrolling: false, option working.
So once the pop up closes you can no longer scroll manually up and down the site. You can use the menu anchors to snap to sections but not scroll. Its normal again once refreshed but will happen again after opening a popup.

Any ideas why this happens and how to resolve it?

Magnific Popup
https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup

fullPage.js https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

fullpage code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            anchors: ['section1','section2'],
            navigation: false,
            scrollOverflow:false,
            showActiveTooltip:true,
            slidesNavigation: false,
            menu:'.menu',
            fixedElements: '#header, #footer',
            paddingTop:'140px',
            autoScrolling: false,
            scrollOverflow: false                   
    });
</script>
```

Magnific Popup code

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.media').magnificPopup({
       removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
       gallery:{enabled:true},
       image:{titleSrc: 'title'},
callbacks: {
beforeOpen: function() {
   this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
}
},
closeOnContentClick: true,
midClick: true
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

MagnificPopup HTML

```
<a href="assets/gallery/Q-awards-1024x682.jpg" class="media mfp-image" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" title="MEDIA"><img src="image.png" width="100%"></a>
```

Comment: You should provide your code. Initialization of both plugins and maybe some HTML markup

Comment: After seeing your FAQ looks like I need to use afterRender() but not sure quite how what alter the example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the plugin's initialization inside the `afterRender` callback as per [fullPage.js FAQs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/wiki/FAQ---Frequently-Answered-Questions#my-other-plugins-dont-work-when-using-fullpagejs):

> **My other plugins don't work when using fullPage.js**
>   **Short answer:** initialize them in the afterRender callback of fullPage.js.
>   **Explanation:** if you are using options such as verticalCentered:true or overflowScroll:true of fullPage.js, your content will be wrapped inside other elements changing its position in the DOM structure of the site. This way, your content would be consider as "dynamically added content" and most plugins need the content to be originally on the site to perform their tasks. Using the afterRender callback to initialize your plugins, fullPage.js makes sure to initialize them only when fullPage.js has stopped changing the DOM structure of the site.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['section1', 'section2'],
        navigation: false,
        scrollOverflow: false,
        showActiveTooltip: true,
        slidesNavigation: false,
        menu: '.menu',
        fixedElements: '#header, #footer',
        paddingTop: '140px',
        autoScrolling: false,
        scrollOverflow: false,
        afterRender: function () {
            $('.media').magnificPopup({
                removalDelay: 500, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
                gallery: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                image: {
                    titleSrc: 'title'
                },
                callbacks: {
                    beforeOpen: function () {
                        this.st.mainClass = this.st.el.attr('data-effect');
                    }
                },
                closeOnContentClick: true,
                midClick: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work the behaviour is still the same. The pop up opens but when closed scrolling is no longer available.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site or reproduce your problem in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Here's think link it wasn't live yet, click the middle image to open the pop up. http://www.wearehawkes.com/hawkes#mediaSection

Comment: Looks like a problem with the pop up plugin which doesn't create the scroll bar after its closed. You'd better open another question regarding that specific issue.

Comment: I guess you can also update it by yourself using the `magnificPopup` callback and setting the `html, body` elements to `overflow:visible`.

Comment: I added this to my callback for magnific popup and its working now! Many thanks for your advice. 
`afterClose: function() {
     document.body.style.overflow="visible";
  }`